# How do I ask for a parameter to be a mutable Map?

Tags: java, collections, guava

I have a function that accepts a `Map` of parameters, but adds to them before using them:

```
public String doRequest(String endpoint, Map<String, String> parameters) {
    parameters.put("limit", "50");
    ...
}
```

It's convenient to create this map using Guava's `ImmutableMap.of()`:

```
doRequest("/comments", ImmutableMap.of("filter", "true"));
```

However, this throws a `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` at runtime.

Two questions:

1) Can I declare `doRequest` in a way that for example `HashMap` and `TreeMap` would be fine but using `ImmutableMap` would be a compile time error?

2) From inside `doRequest`, how would I detect that it's an `ImmutableMap`, so I could run `params = Maps.newHashMap(params)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Can I declare doRequest in a way that for example HashMap and TreeMap would be fine but using ImmutableMap would be a compile time error?

No. As `ImmutableMap` implements `Map`, it can't be a compile time error. The problem is actually with `Map.put`, which allows to throw. It'd better to have a `Map` without `put` and an `MutableMap` interface... but there's nothing what anyone could do about it in Java as all the software around relies on it.

> 2) From inside doRequest, how would I detect that it's an ImmutableMap, so I could run params = Maps.newHashMap(params)?

You'd better do it always as there's also `Collections.unmodifiableMap` and actually everyone could implement a `Map` refusing `put`.

If you're concerned with performance, then you'll need an `instanceof` check.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the fact an `ImmutableMap` is a `Map` is bad subtyping and a violation of the LSP - this is you paying for it. A subtype not being able to fulfil its parent type's contract... this is `ImmutableMap` inheriting from map being bad OOP (since `Map` specifies a `put`) and Java not providing strong enough constructs to enforce those guarantees.

As for a solution - either *document* that you're going to mutate the `Map` passed in, or as an alternative don't mutate the `Map` that's passed in - instead return a new `ImmutableMap` yourself.

Comment: As for detecting type - you can use `instanceof`, yes - it's bad oop but then again so is `ImmutableMap` inheriting from `Map` in the first place.

Comment: Please tell me how [`ImmutableMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html) violates the [contract of `Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)? Remove that rant to get my +1.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire sure, `Map` exposes a [`put` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-) which implies you can add things to a `Map` - this is a violation of the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) - a better design would be not to have a `put` method on `Map` and instead have a `MutableMap` that `TreeMap` and `HashMap` inherit from, or to have a stronger notion of constness in the language.

Comment: I agree with you, just don't say that ImmutableMap implementing Map is a bad subtyping. Also, the child class totally fulfills the parent's type contract. I don't see the reasons of your rant against ImmutableMap. Against Map, I agree, but not against ImmutableMap.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I'm not saying that ImmutableMap is a bad idea, in fact most of my work and a lot of my own code is with immutable collections. However - ImmutableMap implementing `Map` is in fact a bad idea, because it implies it can do things it really can't (like `put`) and this is exactly the mine OP stepped on - I agree it's not `ImmutableMap`s fault (since it makes sense to implement Map there because it's what people expect in Java) it's more of  `Map`s fault - but that doesn't make it less bad oop.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: The contract of `Map` _explicitly_ allows mutative operations to be unsupported on a `Map` implementation. You can certainly argue that `Map` shouldn't be specified that way, but it does greatly simplify the type hierarchy of the collections framework and isn't a significant problem in practice as long as you don't assume that any arbitrary `Map` you're given is mutable without making that an explicit requirement of your method (it sounds like you agree on this anyway).

Comment: Well, obviously it's a problem in practice since OP asked a question about it so people are running into the issue. How can you make an explicit requirement that the map is mutable? This is what the OP is asking here and the given way collections is laid out - there is no trivial way to do this.